# Add-in Behavior is Office 2013 MSI

Tags: add-in, office-js

We are trying to use the **Adobe Sign Add-in** in Word 2013/2016 MSI version and we notice that the behavior is different than when i load the same add-in in Office 2016 Click2Run version.
In 2013 i do not see the add-in in the Home tab, though i can see the task pane loaded.

Steps - 
Open Word 2013 msi
Click INSERT ->Store
Search for Adobe Sign for Word and Powerpoint
Install it.
You do not see anything added in ribbon

Try the same step in Office 2016 click2run you see the add-in added in Home tab

is this expected behavior?
May someone please share a link explaining this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Add-in commands are not supported in Word 2013.

For more information on supported platforms for add-in commands see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands#supported-platforms)